# How to fetch full table in function in snowflake and test that it is working fine or not

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function FN_TABLE_ROWS() returns TABLE(ID NUMBER,NAME VARCHAR) as     
'select 111 AS ID,'   ' NEERAJ'' AS NAME from DUAL';  

Select FN_TABLE_ROWS() from dual;
```

Comment: Writing in ALL UPPERCASE is considered shouting and rude around here. Please also read the only help about [formatting your code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). You should also put your actual question into the body of your question not into the title. Please read [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then **[EDIT]** your question and add the missing information.

Answer (score 1):

We can select the function as given below.

select * from table(FN_TABLE_ROWS());